# Javascript: Get instance getter and fields names or names and values

Tags: javascript

I usually use the next sentence to obtain all object fields but I just realized that is skips object getters

```
Object.entries(myInstance)
```

I also tried without results:

```
Object.keys(myInstance)
Object.values(myInstance)
```

There is any way to traverse the object attributes AND getters? I am interested in the name and value of the getter not the function itself.

Comment: `Object.entries()` does *not* skip the properties with getters; it includes the property names and the results of calling the getter functions.

Comment: Please show us the object in question. If the getter property has been added with its `enumerable` flag set to false, it will not be enumerated by methods like `Object.entries`. To test for this, try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myInstance)`. Alternatively, the field you want might be on the prototype chain, not on the object itself.

Comment: You can write a loop that traverses everything in a object, you then just need to check the iterator with typeof to establish if its type then mange it correctly, typeof is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make the getter enumerable using Object.defineProperty to define the instance with the config to allow it to be enumerable. Substituting 'this' for a reference to your object below.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'getterName' {
   enumerable: true,
   get: function() {
       return 'value'
   }
}
```

[MDN: Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 2):

If a class declaration defines a method or a getter, they will defined on the prototype, and are not enumerable.

That is, they will appear neither of `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `Reflect.ownKeys` (they won't look up prototypes), nor in a `for..in` loop (it skips non-enumerable properties).

You have three ways:

- Make the getter enumerable:

```js
class Foo{
  /* contents of class */
}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'bar', {
  get: () => 'baz',
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false //Or true
})
for(const prop in new Foo){
  console.log(prop)
}
```

- Define the getter on instances:

```js
class Foo{
  constructor() {
     Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', {
      get: () => 'baz',
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: false //Or true
    })
  }
  /* contents of class */
}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Foo))
```

- Implement a custom lookup algorithm:

```js
class Foo{
  get bar(){return 'baz'}
  /* class contents here */
}

Object.getAllPropertyNames = obj => new Set(obj != null //not null or undefined 
  ? [
    ...Reflect.ownKeys(obj),
    ...Object.getAllPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))
  ]
  : undefined
)

console.log(Array.from(Object.getAllPropertyNames(new Foo)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames
```

From MDN web docs: "The Object.getOwnPropertyNames() method returns an array of all properties (including non-enumerable properties except for those which use Symbol)"